# How to set focus on listbox after the sub ends VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I currently enable and disable in different subs where `tbA` is a textbox, `lbA` & `lbB` are listboxes, `Generate`, `Reset` & `Clse` are buttons. There are other codes under these, but I've shorten to show the least amount to reproduce.

After enabling lbA & lbB for input I `SetFocus` to lbA, but as soon as the sub ends, my focus goes to either `Reset` or `Close`

```
Private Sub Userform_Activate

    lbA.Enabled = False
    lbB.Enabled = False
    Generate.Enabled = False

End Sub


Private Sub tbA_AfterUpdate()

If tbA.TextLength > 0 Then

    tbA.Enabled = False
    lbA.Enabled = True
    lbB.Enabled = True
    Generate.Enabled = True

    lbA.SetFocus

Elseif tbA.TextLength = 0 Then

    Msgbox "Invalid Input"
    Exit Sub

End If  'setting focus works up till here 

End Sub 'as soon as this sub ends, and it's time for user to input lbA & lbB
        'it loses focus to the Reset & Close button


Private Sub Generate_Click()

    Msgbox tbA & "from " & lbA " to " & lbB
End

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before `SetFocus` select a item in LbA. like `LbA.Selected(0) = True` :      `LbA.SetFocus`. Also may be typo of `tbAC` in line `Elseif tbAC.TextLength = 0 Then`. Further use `Value` `Text` etc in  `MsgBox` .statement with `TbA` and `LbA`  etc

Comment: @AhmedAU thank you for pointing out, have corrected that in my codes. the current code works if I stop the code before `End Sub`. As soon as it finishes running that sub, it focuses onto `Reset` instead of my previous `lbA.SetFocus`